# python web scraping - Golf Handicap

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm somewhat of a beginner so i think this should be an easy one, however, having flicked through the bs4 documentation i'm struggling to find a solution.

If you know anything about golf it may help answer this.

I am trying to extract the handicap number in the big orange box on this page http://www.golf.org.au/Handicap/3012801370. Currently the numbers says 14.3 although this changes.

My program

```
import requests, bs4
res = requests.get('http://www.golf.org.au/Handicap/3012801370')
res.raise_for_status()
gethcp = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")
hcp = gethcp.select('#ctl11_lblExactHandicap')
type(hcp)
hcp[0].getText()
```

I'm guessing im doing something wrong in this part.. ..(res.text,..

Any guidance is much appreciated

Comment: I don't see the string `ExactHandicap` anywhere in the HTML of that link (nor do I see a big orange anything).  Presumably, it is created by JavaScript after the HTML loads.  If so, you'll have to figure out where that content comes from or how it's created before you can scrape it.

Answer (score -1):

Your code is fine. The problem is you're being redirected to this page,

http://www.golf.org.au/handicap-interstitial/3012801370

where you need to choose 'SKIP TO VIEW YOUR HANDICAP HISTORY >>'. You could do this with `Selenium`, or add a session cookie, but in this case it can be accomplished by using the `href` of the skip option. So that would look like:

```
import requests, bs4

# Changed URL
res = requests.get('http://www.golf.org.au/handicap-interstitial/3012801370/Skip')

res.raise_for_status()
gethcp = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")
hcp = gethcp.select('#ctl11_lblExactHandicap')
type(hcp)
hcp[0].getText()
```

This will give you the expected output of '14.3'.